# Tables: how to parametrize ruler dimensions (e.g. thickness)?

Tags: tables, variable

I would like to define the parameters of my table rulers using some sort of variables, so that just by changing the variables definitions I can tweak the rulers without further need to change the table code. For instance, in the example  below I would like to use variables for the quantities in the places noted in the comments. How can I accomplish this? Thanks, Jorge.

Example:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\cmidrule[1.0pt](l{-0.4pt}){2-3}        % <- would like to parametrize 1.0pt and -0.4pt
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& Text& Text \\
\cmidrule[2.0pt]{1-3}       % <- would like to parametrize 2.0pt
Text& Text& Text \\
\cmidrule[3.0pt]{1-3}       % <- would like to parametrize 3.0pt
Text& Text& Text \\
\midrule[4.0pt]     % <- would like to parametrize 4.0pt
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by parameterize? Do you want to set those in the beginning of the document, beginning of the table, or just use a macro with those parameters in-place? You could define lengths by `\newlength{\tabparone}
\setlength{\tabparone}{1pt}` and use them by `\tabparone`. If that is what you're looking for.

Comment: But you already use parameters for `\cmidrule`s! What more do you want?

Comment: Yes! I'd like to make all these definitions in one place in my code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks nox; that in fact does the trick!:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex

\newlength{\RuleOffsetLeft} \setlength{\RuleOffsetLeft}{-0.4pt}
\newlength{\RuleThicknessNormal} \setlength{\RuleThicknessNormal}{1.0pt}
\newlength{\RuleThicknessThick} \setlength{\RuleThicknessThick}{2.0pt}
\newlength{\RuleThicknessVeryThick} \setlength{\RuleThicknessVeryThick}{3.0pt}
\newlength{\RuleThicknessExtremelyThick} \setlength{\RuleThicknessExtremelyThick}{4.0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\cmidrule[\RuleThicknessNormal](l{\RuleOffsetLeft}){2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& Text& Text \\
\cmidrule[\RuleThicknessThick]{1-3}
Text& Text& Text \\
\cmidrule[\RuleThicknessVeryThick]{1-3}
Text& Text& Text \\
\midrule[\RuleThicknessExtremelyThick]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```